# Fancybox 3 complex image caption as DIV

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm a rookie at Javascript, Jquery and Fancybox. Building an image gallery site for a client. Image captions are complicated (headers, paragraphs, PayPal form, etc.) Trying to make a DIV with all the markup render properly in fancybox-slide, to no avail. Please help! Sample markup:

The Link

```
<a href="../assets/img/illustration/2018-02-Roi-de-coeur.jpg" data-title-id="roi-de-coeur" data-fancybox="gallery" class="card roi-de-coeur"></a>
```

The DIV I'm trying to render properly

```
    <div id="roi-de-coeur" class="fancybox-caption">
        <h4>Le Roi de coeur</h4>
        <p>Scratchboard on Masonite with watercolor, 7&#34; h x 5&#34; w (2018). For upcoming <span class="pubTitle"><a href="http://bostoncomics.com/" target="_blank">Boston Comics Roundtable</a> Card Deck</span>. Framed original art $150 USD + $15 shipping</p>
        <form target="paypal" action="URL" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="">
            <input type="image" src="" name="submit" alt="">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="" width="1" height="1">
        </form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you put this into the code snippet which replicates your issue - this will help us see the issue and help?

Comment: Just did, days later. See below, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs, there are some samples that should help (especially, the last one) - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#faq-2 e.g.,

```
$( '[data-fancybox]' ).fancybox({
    caption : function( instance, item ) {
        return 'html code of some other element that can contain anything';
    }
});
```

Comment: So close. I couldn't use the Janis Skarnelis method ([link](https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/aaerxw)), since my figcaption content has anchor tags (itself a child of an anchor tag, creating nested anchor tags Fancybox won't render). I'm trying to merge the older "title-id" solution into the new Fancybox, but my javascript inexperience is getting in the way. The figcaption content isn't loading into the fancybox-caption DIV. What am I doing wrong? Code below:

Comment: **Markup**
`<a href="" data-title-id="test-1" data-fancybox="image" class="fancybox">`
 `<img src="" />`
`</a>`
`<div id="test-1" class="hidden">`
 `<h4>Art Name</h4>`
 `<p>`
  `Art description with <a href="#">hyperlink</a> elit.` 
  `Sed diam nonummy nibh euismod erat volutpat.`
 `</p>`
`</div>`

Comment: **External scripts**
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.2/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js

Comment: **Header script**
`<script type="text/javascript">`
 `$(document).ready(function() {`
  `$(".fancybox")`
  `.attr('rel', 'gallery')`
  `.fancybox({`
   beforeLoad: function() {`
    `var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');`
    `if (id) {`
     `el = $('#' + id);`
     `if (el.length) {`
      `this.title = el.html();`
     `}`
    `}`
   `}`
  `});`
 `});`
`</script>`

Comment: **Style**
`.hidden {display: none;}`

Comment: Janis, I'm really close this time. The exact markup and functionality I want works on your demo/images page ("Rocky mountain under blue and white sky" example). But the same markup and jquery/Fancybox resources don't work on my local. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response. I got tripped up by the desired functionality being coded two different ways. The [CodePen solution](https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/aaerxw) wrapped the custom comment in an anchor tag, which I couldn't use since the comments have their own anchors, creating embedded anchor tags (`<a>amazingly <a>customized</a> content</a>`) that HTML refused to render. The [Fancybox Demo](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) wraps custom comments in `<figcaption>`, using a different script. I would update the CodePen example to match the Fancybox Demo. Thanks for all your help!